# how to Use UNION and Order by Clause in my JPQL Query

Tags: eclipselink

I am using eclipse link as a JPA in my project. the current jar i am using is eclipselink-2.5.2.Coming to my Question,
 I want to use Order by in UNION combination. My JPQL query looks like following

```
select req from Rqst req  
 WHERE (req.Applc =:SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER1 AND req.procesTyp  =:PROCESS_TYPE1 AND UPPER(req.updtBy) =:UPDATED_BY1) 
 AND req.stat <> :ignoreDeletedRequests 
UNION 
select req from Rqst req 
 WHERE (req.Applc =:SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER2 AND req.procesTyp  =:PROCESS_TYPE2 AND UPPER(req.updtBy) =:UPDATED_BY2) 
 AND req.stat <> :ignoreDeletedRequests 
UNION 
select req from Rqst req 
 WHERE (req.Applc =:SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER3 AND req.procesTyp  =:PROCESS_TYPE3 AND UPPER(req.updtBy) =:UPDATED_BY3) 
 AND req.stat <> :ignoreDeletedRequests 
 ORDER BY req.rqstId ASC
```

With out Order by it is working for me. But when i use Order by I am getting The query contains a malformed ending.

Can any help me here i am stuck for long time.

Comment: JPQL does not have "UNION"

Comment: Yes, but eclipse link support UNION. Only in case of any SORT(Order by) it is not working. if i remove order by it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem as you. I solved that problem by using Collection.sort() like that:

```
Collections.sort(listObjects, new Comparator<Object[]>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(final Object[] record1, final Object[] record2) {
                        int c;
                        c = convertTime(record1[0].toString()).compareTo(convertTime(record2[0].toString()));
                        if (c == 0) {
                            c = record1[1].toString().compareTo(record2[1].toString());
                        }
                        if (c == 0) {
                            c = record1[2].toString().compareTo(record2[2].toString());
                        }
                        if (c == 0) {
                            c = new Long(Long.parseLong(record1[3].toString())).compareTo(Long.parseLong(record2[3].toString()));
                        }
                        if (c == 0) {
                            c = ((Date) record1[4]).compareTo(((Date) record2[4]));
                        }
                        if (c == 0) {
                            c = ((Date) record1[5]).compareTo(((Date) record2[5]));
                        }
                        if (c == 0) {
                            c = new Long(Long.parseLong(record1[6].toString())).compareTo(Long.parseLong(record2[6].toString()));
                        }
                        return c;
                    }

                });
```

You can use Collention.sort() to order multiple fields;